# Struts - Using multiple submit buttons for one form? (How to know which was clicked)

Tags: java, struts

I have 3 buttons for a form I would like to submit. I'm new to struts and I was wondering, is there a way to find which button was clicked? In my html I have this

```
<html:form action="myAction.jspa">
    <div align="right">
        <html:submit value="back" />
        <html:submit value="continue Later" />
        <html:submit value="submit"  />
    </div>
</html:form>
```

And in my Java `Action` class in the `execute()` method, I attempt using `request.getParameter("back")` to check if the back button has been pressed but it doesn't work. How does one handle multiple submit buttons in struts?

Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `property` attribute on your `<html:submit>` tag to specify the name of the request parameter that you'll check in your action.

JSP

```
<html:submit property="back">back</html:submit>
```

Action

```
if(request.getParameter("back") != null) {
    // back button was clicked
}
```

You can, alternatively, give all of your submit buttons the **same** property, then check the value of the parameter in your action. However, that adds additional internationalization concerns (you'd need to check for non-English translations of the same string).

For more information, see the [Struts API](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#submit).

Answer (score 0):

Either use [DispatchAction](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-extras/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html)  or use javascript and pass value actontype in hidden parameter (back,continue later).

http://unnisworld.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/struts-tip-how-to-organize-related-operations-into-a-single-action-class/

Answer (score 0):

you can get press button id by jquery. Then you know which button has clicked. According to Click button Call struts Action.