# Getting My ActionForward To Recognize Different Submit Buttons - Java and JSP through Struts

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

Getting a bit stuck on the particulars of Struts, sorry for any confusing terminology, I am very new to using Struts.

I am trying to get my ActionForward Handler class to recognize the different Submit button inputs that the JSP page sends to it in order to get different results.

What I have at the moment are two buttons: Submit and Cancel.  When clicked, they pass database information through a validating method in one class on into another method in an action handling class (EditThis.doIt), and my task is to add a third button to delete this information.  What I am trying to do is add a Delete button as a submit button, like so:

```
 <div align="left"> &nbsp;
 <html:submit value="Submit" styleClass="button"/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
 <html:cancel styleClass="button"/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
 <html:submit value="Delete" styleClass="button"/>
 </div>
```

But I have no idea how to get the ActionForward to recognize the difference between Delete and Submit.  What can I do, keeping within Struts, to achieve this?

Comment: Got my answer from this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986599/struts-using-multiple-submit-buttons-for-one-form-how-to-know-which-was-clic?rq=1

No longer need an answer for this, but if anyone's looking for one themselves, the first one using "property" to identify the buttons with unique names worked for my problem.  

Thank you to any and all who were trying to think of a solution to this for me.  :)

Comment: Just a terminology thing, those aren't "ActionForward handlers", they're "actions".

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understand your question.When you click the submit button,you call the "excute()" method in the Action class.But you want to click the delete button to do another thing in the same action.Is it right?
If I'm right,my suggestion is

declare another action in the struts.xml and use the same action class as the submit button,declaration the method in this action which you want to use.

Here is a struts.xml which is in my project

```
    <action name="elecDeleteAction" class="com.gs.action.ElecAction" method="delete">
        <result name="success">/elec/elecadmin/deletesuccess.jsp</result>
        <result name="fail">/elec/elecadmin/deletefail.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="elecIndexAction" class="com.gs.action.ElecAction" method="index">
        <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

It's to say use the property "method" to declare the method which you want to call.

Comment: Wrong version of Struts.